# 409 - This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet.\r\nclientRequestId: 9f1c2167-ef13-4c30-b1ee-ed56519a54db

Tags: excel, power-automate, logic-app

I am trying to add rows of data to an excel sheet using a logic app. The headers of the table are created in a different step.

Any ideas on how to fix this, I have tried googling the error code but not much is returning in the search results. I am receiving the error in the title.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many tables you have on this excel sheet?

Comment: There is a table on the first worksheet with data. The screenshot above is a second worksheet created by the logic app.

Comment: There is only one table on that excel worksheet.

Comment: The issue in the excel sheet itself, try to do the same action in new excel file and check

Comment: This needs to be an automated solution though, I'll try again with a new file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out!!! - I can see so many people having this issue without a proper fix, so I hope this helps a lot of people.

When creating my table range, I have added 1's to A and G so the table doesn't go down to the end of the spreadsheet which was mucking it up :)

Do this:

```
='Customer Infomation'!A1:G1
```

Instead of this:

```
='Customer Infomation'!A:G
```

Comment: This is one of the most stunning and important finding ever! Thank you!

Comment: @Ariser Haha you made my day! :D - My gf is an accountant so she helped me with this lol